# Android voice modulator

Tags: android, voice, speech, soundeffect

I want to create an android app that inputs the user's voice and modulate it in real-time.
Therefore, I wanted to ask if there are any libraries or functions to input the speech/voice and change its pitch,etc.

Any in built functions...?

Thank you.